# How to find children HTML with beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For my first experience in Python, I'm using `Selenium` and `Beautifulsoup` to retrieve article titles from a website. However, I'm having trouble to take child from a `div`, I just find the first `span` but not the second...

I present you the `div` :

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between font-size-14 font-weight-bold">
                                    <span>Porte</span>
                                    <span>epoxy blanc</span>
</div>
```

I tried that :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

items = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-12 col-sm-6 product--description--content--item"})
children = items.find_all("span")
print(len(children))
```

Comment: Just in addition to my edits - Take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions in the future. Providing an example of your expected result would also be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="d-flex justify-content-between font-size-14 font-weight-bold"> <span>Porte</span> <span>epoxy blanc</span> </div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

spans = soup.find_all('span')

for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

I hope you can modify my code whatever need you.

Also can try this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', class_='d-flex justify-content-between font-size-14 font-weight-bold')

spans = div.find_all('span')

for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I think I expressed myself poorly. There are several divs each containing 2 spans. I am able to retrieve each first span of each div but not the second one."

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it will helpful for your.

Comment: Thanks you very much, now I can't find every div with the same nameee

Comment: sorry! I fin the good way to retrieve the goods informations, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find_next_sibling()` to specify the element that you are looking for based on the one you still found:

```
soup.span.find_next_sibling('span')
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="d-flex justify-content-between font-size-14 font-weight-bold"> <span>Porte</span> <span>epoxy blanc</span> </div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.span.find_next_sibling('span')
```

Output:

```
<span>epoxy blanc</span>
```